# Using .htaccess with IIS

Tags: iis, htaccess

It is necessary for me to make it possible for `.htaccess` files to be usable with IIS. Is there a way for this to be done? I know that on its own, IIS is not capable of handling this, but could I perhaps install some third party application that could do this for IIS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this software :

http://www.helicontech.com/ape/

> Helicon Ape provides support for Apache .htaccess and .htpasswd
>   configuration files in Microsoft IIS. It literally implements Apache
>   configuration model and nearly all Apache modules in a single IIS
>   add-on, not only making IIS compatible with Apache, but also extending
>   it`s functionality by a number of highly essential features.
>
> Includes following modules: mod_rewrite, mod_proxy, mod_auth,
>   mod_gzip, mod_headers, mod_cache, mod_expires, mod_replace and others.
>   You can check all currently available modules in the compatibility
>   chart (the list is growing with new builds).

http://www.helicontech.com/ape/doc/compatibility.htm

Comment: Thanks! Even though this question is old, I never found a good solution.

Comment: According to [Bjorgen Eatinger](https://superuser.com/users/956149/bjorgen-eatinger)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1376562/201818) Helicon Technology is no longer in business.

Answer (score 8):

In IIS (Internet Information Server) the equivalent of **.htaccess** is  **web.config**

You can read more about Web.config [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7w4sb0w.aspx) and [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815179)

And some htaccess to web.config converting tools [here](http://cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx) and [here](http://www.htaccesstowebconfig.com/)

Comment: MS is pretty horrible at tutorials. Here is a good one: http://www.saotn.org/convert-apache-htaccess-iis-web-config/#.U_QdKvldUqx  I would also be very cautious using an online converter for this purpose. Some of the information in your `.htaccess` file could be best to keep confidential.